# All XAMPP servers not starting on Mac OS 10.9.2

Tags: xampp

All XAMPP servers not starting on Mac OS 10.9.2. It starts for a while and then stops. Any ideas on how to solve it?

This is the Application Log

Starting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
Starting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started

Answer (score 0):

Turn of all XAMPP server including all the running services and then restart the computer. I found the same issue in several cases and solve it like that way. Hope it works.